# How to generate a value in a text field without commiting the form?

Tags: javascript

A user is filling in a form:

```
fname : Firstname
mname : middlename
lname : lastname
fullname : Complete naam
```

Before the user is entering field4 I would like to give already the values fname & mname & lname as a start in fullname. I found out that this should be done as below.

I already made this but something is wrong... I have almost no Javascript experience...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
First name: <input type="text" id="fname"><br>
Middle name: <input type="text" id="mname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" id="lname"><br>
Fullname: <input type="text" id="fullname" onfocus="myFunction()"><br>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("fullname").style.background = "yellow";
    document.getElementById("fullname").value = document.getElementsByTagName("fname").value + document.getElementsByTagName("mname").value + document.getElementsByTagName("lname").value;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `getElementById` instead of `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: Thxs it's one of my first scripts :-)

Comment: Consider also using onblur on each of fname, mname, and lname (use onblur="myFunction()").  This would update the fullname field when the user leaves those fields instead of clicking into fullname.  Another option would be to use onkeypress which could be even better.  Have a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f3t466cj/

Comment: Very intresting. I will definitly going to test this as this can just injected in the page without rewriting the input element... Thxs

Comment: Thxs for this improvement. I just implemented it and it is really really nice !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `getElementsByTagName` method, but the value you are passing to it is the **id** of an element, not the tag name (which would be `"input"`).

[Use `getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to get an element by its id.

Answer (score 0):

Either you could access using getElementById like this:

```html
First name:
<input type="text" id="fname">
<br>Middle name:
<input type="text" id="mname">
<br>Last name:
<input type="text" id="lname">
<br>Fullname:
<input type="text" id="fullname" onfocus="myFunction()">
<br>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("fullname").style.background = "yellow";
    document.getElementById("fullname").value = document.getElementById("fname").value + document.getElementById("mname").value + document.getElementById("lname").value;
  }
</script>
```

OR
Stick to use getElementsByTagName.

```html
First name:
<input type="text" id="fname">
<br>Middle name:
<input type="text" id="mname">
<br>Last name:
<input type="text" id="lname">
<br>Fullname:
<input type="text" id="fullname" onfocus="myFunction()">
<br>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var inputArr = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    document.getElementById("fullname").style.background = "yellow";
    inputArr[3].value = inputArr[0].value + inputArr[1].value + inputArr[2].value;
  }
</script>
```

Sounds good!

Comment: Stick with the first option.  The second option could be error prone if the fields get reordered.  Yes, of course, the first could break if ids change, but even so it's the better option.

Comment: Absolutely agreed!